# Remote execution in a domain environment

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access

I have a windows domain environment and it contains only Server 2008 Os's. I'm trying to execute a script or a program from 1 server  on multiple servers, but I can't configure or install any applications. I was trying to user powershell v2.0 (invoke-command) but its not configured and I cant configure it. I'm looking for an alternative maybe WMI. Psexec and rcmd are not installed on any servers. Any advise could help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about copying a script to each machine and adding a scheduled task that executes it?

Also, [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) does not require a remote install. Some information from [PsExec - Execute processes on a remote system and redirect output to the local system](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/remote-computing/psexec) (Windows IT Pro):

> PsExec's ability to run processes remotely with no manual installation of software on the remote system makes deployment easy.

Comment: The problem is that a scheduled task needs manual configuration and I need to run xy stuff any time I need on more then 100 servers. Psexec gets a try.